# Failed to inject value for parameter [xxxx] of class No bean of type [xxxx] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I'm working on a Gradle multi-module project with Micronaut and I need help with the following classes and interface in the `application` module:

**Core project**

```java
@Singleton
public record OrderService(IOrderRepository iOrderRepository) implements IOrderService {
    @Override
    public Optional<Order> findbyId(UUID id) {
        return iOrderRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

**Core project**

```java
@Introspected
public interface IOrderRepository{
    Optional<Order> findById(@NonNull @NotBlank UUID id);
}
```

**dependency of core project**

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:${micronautVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:${micronautVersion}"

    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject:${micronautVersion}"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:${micronautVersion}"
}
```

The implementation of `IOrderRepository` is in the `infrastructure` module as below:

**infrastructure project**

```java
@Singleton
public record OrderRepository(RootProvider<Root> rootProvider) implements IOrderRepository {
    @Override
    public Optional<Order> findById(@NonNull UUID id) {
        return rootProvider.root().order().get(id);
    }
}
```

**dependency of infrastructure**

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:${micronautVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:${micronautVersion}"

    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject:${micronautVersion}"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:${micronautVersion}"
}
```

Here's a visual representation of the project structure:

[image]

[image]

The `infrastructure` project depends on the `core` project. Since the definition of `IOrderRepository` is in the `core` module and implementation of the `IOrderRepository` is in `infrastructure`, I'm not sure how to handle the dependencies correctly.

**The issue is that `OrderRepository` is in different module then the `IOrderRepository` module, that doesn't have a dependency. How can I will refer to different module ?**

```
Message: No bean of type [fete.bird.interfaces.IOrderRepository] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
Path Taken: new $OrderController$Definition$Intercepted(IServiceBus iServiceBus,BeanResolutionContext $beanResolutionContext,BeanContext $beanContext,Qualifier $qualifier,List $interceptors) --> new $OrderController$Definition$Intercepted([IServiceBus iServiceBus],BeanResolutionContext $beanResolutionContext,BeanContext $beanContext,Qualifier $qualifier,List $interceptors) --> new ServiceBus([List handlers]) --> new GetOrderQueryHandler([IOrderService iOrderService]) --> new OrderService([IOrderRepository iOrderRepository])
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2087)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1297)
    at fete.bird.service.$OrderService$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
```

**GitHub Repo** - https://github.com/anandjaisy/order-dependency-issue

Answer (score 0):

It is great that you have a sample project; however, your sample project uses a non-public dependency. (Cannot build your project)

In your `core` and `infrastructure`, use the [Micronaut Library Plugin](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gradle-plugin/latest/#_micronaut_library_plugin):

```
plugins {
  id 'io.micronaut.library' version '3.7.10'
}
```

Comment: Update the project you can now take the latest and build should be fine. However adding id 'io.micronaut.library' version '3.7.10' also not working. Same issue

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below dependency to the API project worked for me

```
runtimeOnly project(':infrastructure')
```